# Get Next Day date with fix time in PHP

Tags: php

Hello i am writing a module in PHP. Here I have to check for the condition like if user select demo for application with basic features he should get demo for next day till 12 PM. I am using code

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
echo date("Y-m-d 12:00:00",strtotime('tomorrow'))
```

it is working fine. But when user try for demo account in mid night that is same date as next day. it is giving me the day after tomorrow date. For example today is 22/01/2014 before  22/01/2014 11:59PM it is working fine. but  23/01/2014 00:01 AM it is giving date 24/01/2014 12:01PM but i want it to be 23/01/2014 12:01PM. Any suggestion.

Comment: What do you want to happen? If I register at 00:01 I will only get 12 hours demo, but if I register at 08:00 I will get 28 hours demo? What is your cut off time?

Comment: i want to off demo next day at 12:00 PM either he apply today or same day before 12:00 PM

Comment: So if I apply at 11:00 I will get 1 hour demo, or if I apply at 11:59 I will get 1 minute demo. Are these both correct?

Comment: Yes, same thing i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

$day = date('H') < 12 ? 'today' : 'tomorrow';
echo date("Y-m-d 12:00:00",strtotime($day));
```

The key is to work out which day the demo should end, this can be done by checking the current hour. If the current hour is less than 12, then it should be today's date, otherwise tomorrow's.